Button Edit using Fluent UI Blazor Wasm
Please anyone can help me?
Anyone can help me to create a Edit Button sending Id as parameter? I already tried many different ways.
    <FluentDataGrid Id="jobreferencerules" Items="@forecasts" TGridItem="My Class">
        <PropertyColumn Title="Id" Property="@(c => c!.Id)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Group Code" Property="@(c => c!.Group.Pessoa.Cd_Pes)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Group Name" Property="@(c => c!.Group.Pessoa.Apelido)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Modal Code" Property="@(c => c!.Tipo_Modal_Imp_Exp.Cd_Tp_Modal)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Doc Code" Property="@(c => c!.Tipo_Doc_Cliente.ID_DC)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Doc Name" Property="@(c => c!.Tipo_Doc_Cliente.Nome_DC)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Status" Property="@(c => c!.Enabled)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Created By" Property="@(c => c!.User.Nome_Usuario)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Created Date" Property="@(c => c!.Insert_Date)" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />
        
       <<<<<<<<BUTTON EDIT HERE>>>>>>>>
    </FluentDataGrid>

@code {
private void Edit(int id)
{
NavManager.NavigateTo($"/editjobreferencerules/{id}");
}
}
Just someone help me

Here's a page from a Demo site of mine that adds edit and view buttons to a grid showing weather forecasts.  I've left all the code in so [hopefully] you can see how things plug together.
@namespace Blazr.App.UI.FluentUI
@inject IFluentGridPresenter<DmoWeatherForecast> Presenter
@inject IDialogService DialogService

<PageTitle>Weather Forecasts</PageTitle>

<FluentHeader Style="background-color: transparent; color: black;">
    <h3>Weather Forecasts</h3>
    <FluentSpacer />
    <FluentButton Color="var(--info)" IconStart="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.AddCircle())"
                  OnClick="@OnAddAsync">
        New Weather Forecast
    </FluentButton>
</FluentHeader>

<FluentDataGrid Id="weathergrid" 
    ItemsProvider="this.Presenter.GetItemsAsync<DmoWeatherForecast>" 
        Pagination="_pagination"
        TGridItem=DmoWeatherForecast>
    <PropertyColumn Title="Id" Property="@(c => c!.WeatherForecastId.Value.ToDisplayId())" Align=Align.Start />
    <PropertyColumn Title="Date" Property="@(c => c!.Date)" Format="dd-MMM-yy" Sortable="true" IsDefaultSortColumn InitialSortDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" Align=Align.Start />
    <PropertyColumn Title="Temp &deg; C" Sortable="true" Format="N0" Property="@(c => c!.Temperature.TemperatureC)" Align=Align.End />
    <PropertyColumn Title="Temp &deg; F" Sortable="true" Format="N0" Property="@(c => c!.Temperature.TemperatureF)" Align=Align.End />
    <PropertyColumn Title="Summary" Sortable="true" Property="@(c => c!.Summary)" Align=Align.Center />
    <TemplateColumn Title="Actions" Align="@Align.End">
        <FluentButton aria-label="View item" IconEnd="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.ContentView())" OnClick="() => OnViewAsync(context.WeatherForecastId)" />
        <FluentButton aria-label="Edit item" IconEnd="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.Edit())" OnClick="() => OnEditAsync(context.WeatherForecastId)" />
    </TemplateColumn>
</FluentDataGrid>

<FluentPaginator State="_pagination" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
    private PaginationState _pagination = new PaginationState { ItemsPerPage = 10 };
    private GridSort<DmoWeatherForecast> sortByName = GridSort<DmoWeatherForecast>
    .ByAscending(p => p.Temperature.TemperatureC);

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (this.PageSize != _pagination.ItemsPerPage)
            _pagination.ItemsPerPage = this.PageSize;
    }

    private async Task OnEditAsync(WeatherForecastId id)
    {
        var dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<WeatherForecastEditForm>(id, new DialogParameters()
            {
                Title = $"Edit Weather Forecast",
                PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                PreventScroll = true,
            });

        var result = await dialog.Result;
    }

    private async Task OnViewAsync(WeatherForecastId id)
    {
        var dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<WeatherForecastViewForm>(id, new DialogParameters()
            {
                Title = $"View Weather Forecast",
                PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                PreventScroll = true,
            });

        var result = await dialog.Result;
    }

    private async Task OnAddAsync()
    {
        var id = new WeatherForecastId(Guid.Empty);
        var dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<WeatherForecastEditForm>(id, new DialogParameters()
            {
                Title = $"New Weather Forecast",
                PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                PreventScroll = true,
            });

        var result = await dialog.Result;
    }
}


You could use TemplateColumn to extract "context.Id". Try following:
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

    <FluentDataGrid Id="jobreferencerules" Items="@forecasts" TGridItem="MyClass">
        <PropertyColumn Title="Id" Property="@(c => c!.Id)" Sortable="true" Align="Align.Start" />   
        <TemplateColumn Title="Actions" Align="@Align.End">
            <FluentButton OnClick="@(()=>{Edit(context.Id); })">Edit</FluentButton>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </FluentDataGrid>

@code{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
    IQueryable<MyClass> forecasts = new List<MyClass>
    {
        new MyClass{ Id=2 },
        new MyClass{ Id=3 }
    }
    .AsQueryable();

    private void Edit(int id)
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"/editjobreferencerules/{id}");
    }
}

Test result

